# dojo datagrid event attach issue

Tags: events, datagrid, dojo

I am working with IBM Content Navigator 2.0.3, that uses DOJO 1.8 for the GUI development. I am new in dojo, and I have to enhance one of the forms: add an event handler to the `dataGrid` so when the row of the grid is selected one of the buttons become enabled.

`dataGrid` described in HTML as follows:

```
<div class="selectedGridContainer" data-dojo-attach-point="_selectedDataGridContainer">                     
    <div class="selectedGrid" data-dojo-attach-point="_selectedDataGrid" ></div>
</div>
```

And the JS file that controls the form behavior mentioned this `_selectedDataGrid` only once, in the `postCreate` function:

```
postCreate: function() {
    this.inherited(arguments);
    this.textDir = has("text-direction");
    this.hoverHelpList = [];
    domClass.add(this._selectedDataGridContainer, "hasSorting");
    this._renderSelectedGrid();
```

`_renderSelectedGrid()` is being executed, which contains the only mention:

```
_renderSelectedGrid: function() {
    .......
    this._selectedDataGrid.appendChild(this._selectedGrid.domNode);
```

I've tried to add an data-dojo-attach-event `onRowClick: enableRemoveUsersButton` in the HTML and a

```
enableRemoveUsersButton: function(evt){
    this.removeUsersButton.set('disabled', true);
},
```

in js file. Didn't help.

Then I tried:

```
dojo.connect(myGrid, "onRowclick", function update() {
    this.removeUsersButton.set('disabled', true); });
```

but I couldn't acquire `myGrid` object using:

```
`var myGrid  = dojo.byId("_selectedDataGrid");`
```

Can anyone tell me how to acquire the grid object and/or add an event handler to this grid, that fires when the row of the grid is selected?

Thank you!

Comment: <div class="selectedGridContainer" data-dojo-attach-point="_selectedDataGridContainer">                     
              <div class="selectedGrid" data-dojo-attach-point="_selectedDataGrid" ></div>
          </div>

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to get the `grid` object by `dojo.byId("_selectedDataGrid")`. It is better to keep the `myGrid` object at class level (widget level) and `connect` using `dojo.hitch`.

```
dojo.connect(this.myGrid, 'onRowClick', dojo.hitch(this, function(){
        //access myGrid using this.myGrid and do the handling
}));
```

Comment: HI. But where do I get myGrid as an input param for the function you provided?

Comment: Wherever you are creating the `grid` object, store it in `this.myGrid`.

Comment: Thanks. I've made it.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have share, I can see that the node "_selectedDataGrid" is just a Div tag. and your dataGrid widget may be "this._selectedGrid" so you should be add the event on that widget not the container node.

Also there is dijit.byId to get the instance of dijits/widgets. and dojo.byId is used to search of dom nodes.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Hi. I've managed to add a event on this._selectedDataGrid, but the event fires when I just click on any part of the grid, without even selecting a row. When I tried to make a check:
    var selectedItems = this._selectedDataGrid.selection.getSelected();
     if (selectedItems.length > 0) {......
nothing happens.

Comment: May be you want to use onSelected or onSelectionChanged event rather than RowClick